# Create and reference a string literal via LLVM C interface

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to create a string literal via LLVM C API, and get a C style pointer to its first member. `LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr` does the trick nicely, but I can't use it because my source string might contain nulls.

I cannot seem to find documentation on how to create an initialized, unnamed, constant global string.

I've tried using `LLVMConstString` to create the string and `LLVMConstIntToPtr` to get its address (and, then, GetElementPointer to convert to `i8*`). I can get LLVM to compile it, but the resulting object file does not contain the string, and the code returns a pointer that seems random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer. The following code segment seems to do the trick:

```
LLVMValueRef defineStringLiteral( const char *sourceString, size_t size ) {
    LLVMTypeRef strType = LLVMArrayType( LLVMInt8Type(), size );
    LLVMValueRef str = LLVMAddGlobal(module->getLLVMModule(), strType, "");
    LLVMSetInitializer(str, LLVMConstString( sourceString, size, true ));
    LLVMSetGlobalConstant(str, true);
    LLVMSetLinkage(str, LLVMPrivateLinkage);
    LLVMSetUnnamedAddress(str, LLVMGlobalUnnamedAddr);
    LLVMSetAlignment(str, 1);


    LLVMValueRef zeroIndex = LLVMConstInt( LLVMInt64Type(), 0, true );
    LLVMValueRef indexes[2] = { zeroIndex, zeroIndex };

    LLVMValueRef gep = LLVMBuildInBoundsGEP2(builder, strType, str, indexes, 2, "");

    return gep;
}
```

Comment: So basically what you did is equivalent to creating a `char` array in C and copying in the `const char*` with `strcpy`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The operations listed take place during compile time. There is no run-time copying of the string. It is placed in the `rodata`, as you'd expect.

Comment: It's not a question It's an observation.

Comment: Then the observation is wrong. LLVM's initializers aren't strcpy (nor even memcpy). All of these modifications in LLVM happen retroactively at the point of code generation.

Comment: That's why I said **equivalent**.  Initializing an `i8` array with an `const char *` is analogous to doing a strcpy into an array of the same type. Just because the latter happens at runtime doesn't mean they're not identical.